# Black screen while AsyncTask is running

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progress-bar

I'm new to asking questions here so any advice about that will be appreciated...but to my problem:

I'm trying to switch from one activity to another, where I'll show some data from the server. I'm pulling the data from server via AsyncTask but there is black screen showing between the activities, when the download is longer. I already tried to put the AsyncTask from onCreate() to onStart() but no change there.

New activity:

```
public class SalesMenu extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
    setContentView(R.layout.sales_menu);        
    setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    List<HashMap<String, Object>> result = null;
    AsyncTask<Void, Boolean, List<HashMap<String, Object>>> aTask = new AsyncSearchRead(
            "sale.order", 
            new Object[0], 
            new String[] {"name"}, 
            this).execute();

    try {
        result = aTask.get();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.d("test", (result!=null ? result.toString() : "nothing"));
    super.onStart();
}

}
```

My AsyncTask:

```
public class AsyncSearchRead extends AsyncTask<Void, Boolean, List<HashMap<String, Object>>> {
String mModel; 
boolean mCount; 
Integer mOffset;
Integer mLimit; 
String mOrder; 
boolean mReverseOrder; 
Object[] mConditions;
String[] mFields;
Activity parentActivity;

public AsyncSearchRead(String model, boolean count, Integer offset, Integer limit, 
                    String order, boolean reverseOrder, Object[] conditions, String[] fields,
                    Activity activity) {
    mModel = model;
    mCount = count;
    mOffset = offset;
    mLimit = limit;
    mOrder = order;
    mReverseOrder = reverseOrder;
    mConditions = conditions;
    mFields = fields;
    parentActivity = activity;
}

@Override
protected List<HashMap<String, Object>> doInBackground(Void... params) {
    Long[] ids;
    List<HashMap<String, Object>> results;
            //Downloading the data
    ids = SetServer.connection.search(mModel, mCount, mOffset, mLimit, mOrder, mReverseOrder, mConditions);
    results = SetServer.connection.read(mModel, ids, mFields);

    return results;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(List<HashMap<String, Object>> result) {
    parentActivity.setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
}

}
```

When I did not turn visibility off onPostExecute it kept spinning after showing the activity but it's only shown after the loading.

How can I get it to show the activity and only after that start to load the data and show some progress bar/loader?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: By calling result = aTask.get(); you are forcing the current thread (the UI) to wait until get() gives a result which only happens once your task completes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's because you're using [`.get()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#get%28%29). `.get()` essentially makes an [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) synchronous (makes the main thread wait until it's done), so it's basically like not running the `AsyncTask` at all.

My suggestion is as follows:

1. Move `List<HashMap<String, Object>> result = null;` to be a member variable.
2. Remove the whole `try/catch` statement (the one with `.get()` in it), and the call to `Log.*`.
3. Move your `AsyncTask` to be an inner class of `SalesMenu`.
4. Do `this.result = result` in `onPostExecute()`, as well as whatever other processing you need to do on it.

Comment: Thank you for great advice it realy helped to get rid of .get(). Even though I did not make it an inner class, because I would like to use it from more classes...hope it's not wrong to use it that way.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @Eric's answer, which is very good advice (+1), try putting `super.onCreate()` before `setContentView()`.  As a general rule, the super call should happen before anything else in overridden Android lifecycle methods, and is especially important in the case of these two methods.

Comment: True. But not really an answer to this question.. more of a comment.. [oh well](http://i0.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/original/000/302/170/685.png)

Comment: Fair point. I thought the order of these methods could have been the cause of the black screen specifically, though the UI blocking from .get() seems to be the root issue of the problem. Thanks!

Comment: No worries.. you still get internet points for bringing up a good point.

Comment: This indeed was not a problem in this case but thanks for clarifying the super calls. I really wasn't sure where they should be placed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other excellent asnwers.

In your `doInBackground()` method, to show progress you call `publichProgress()` at regular intervals, which will in turn call `onProgressUpdate()`. `onPostExecute()` is only called **AFTER** `doInBackground()` has returned.

There is a full usage example in the [AsyncTask docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Answer (score 0):

There some points to keep under consideration while doing any long running tasks:
1) Keep them out of main thread
2) Use Async task class for short lived tasks and make them Asynchronous, use handlers with threads
3) Keep out any long running/heavy tasks from oncreate method
4) Do any task after super.onStart(); call under onStart() or onCreate super calls.

Hope this will help you out.