# cancelling AsyncTask and it's progressbar from a handler

Tags: android, android-asynctask, handler

I want to cancel an AsyncTask that sends data to a server after a period of a few seconds. I've got the AsyncTask and handler set up but the progress dialog still spins. How can i cleanly stop the AsyncTask as quick as possible. This is what i have so far. Thanks in advance.

```
private class AsyncPostData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    String dateTimeScanned;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {


       // progressDialog= ProgressDialog.show(NfcscannerActivity.this, 
            //  "Connecting to Server"," Posting data...", true); 

        int buildVersionSdk = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
        int buildVersionCodes = Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD;

        Log.e(TAG, "buildVersionSdk = " + buildVersionSdk 
                + "buildVersionCodes = " + buildVersionCodes);

        int themeVersion;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) {

             themeVersion = 2;

        }else{

             themeVersion = 1;
        }

        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(NfcscannerActivity.this, themeVersion);
        progressDialog.setTitle("Connecting to Server");
        progressDialog.setMessage(" Sending data to server...");
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);

        try{
        progressDialog.show();
        }catch(Exception e){

            //ignore
        }
    };  


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        Log.e(TAG, "carerid in doinbackground = " + params[3] + " dateTimeScanned in AsyncPost for the duplecate TX = " + params[4]);

        dateTimeScanned = params[4];

        return nfcscannerapplication.loginWebservice.postData(params[0], params[1], params[2], params[3], params[4],
                params[5], params[6], params[7] + getVersionName(), params[8], params[9]);

    }

     @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result)
        {
         super.onPostExecute(result);

            try{
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            }catch(Exception e){
                //ignore
            }

            if( result != null && result.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("OK")  ){

                Log.e(TAG, "about to update DB with servertime");
                DateTime sentToServerAt = new DateTime();
                nfcscannerapplication.loginValidate.updateTransactionWithServerTime(sentToServerAt,null);
                nfcscannerapplication.loginValidate.insertIntoDuplicateTransactions(dateTimeScanned);

                tagId = null;
                tagType = null;
                tagClientId = null;

                //called to refresh the unsent transactions textview
                onResume();

            }else if(result != null && result.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("Error: TX duplicated")){
                Log.e(TAG, "response from server is Duplicate Transaction ");


                //NB. the following time may not correspond exactly with the time on the server
                //because this TX has already been processed but the 'OK' never reached the phone,
                //so we are just going to update the phone's DB with the DupTX time so the phone doesn't keep 
                //sending it.

                DateTime sentToServerTimeWhenDupTX = new DateTime();
                nfcscannerapplication.loginValidate.updateTransactionWithServerTime(sentToServerTimeWhenDupTX,null);

                tagId = null;
                tagType = null;
                tagClientId = null;



            }else{

                Toast.makeText(NfcscannerActivity.this,
                        "No phone signal or server problem",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

}//end of AsyncPostData
```

.

```
public void initHandlerCancelAsyncPost(){

    cancelAsyncPostHandler = new Handler();
      cancelAsyncpostRunnable = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                cancelAsyncPost();

            }

            private void cancelAsyncPost() {

                apd.cancel(true);

            }
        };

    }
```

.

```
public void sendTransactionToWebservice(String statusForWbService){



        initHandlerCancelAsyncPost();
        cancelAsyncPostHandler.postDelayed(cancelAsyncpostRunnable, 8 * 1000);

        String[] params = new String[]{compID, tagId, tagClientId, carerID,
                formattedTagScanTime, formattedNowTime, statusForWbService, getDeviceName(), tagLatitude, tagLongitude}; 
        apd = new AsyncPostData();
        apd.execute(params);

    }
```

Comment: Looks good. I have a suggestion though. I don't know if this is the only `AsyncTask` you have in your activity(probably not), but since you are using `execute()`(serial execution), there might be a chance that `apd` awaits execution while the Handler tries to `cancel()` it. So, it may be better to initialize the `Handler` from `onPreExecute()` of your `AsyncTask`.

Comment: ok thanks for that. Do you know why the progressbar still spins after the handler executes. i think i have to listen for onCancel in the asynctask...

Comment: Yes, you need to override `onCancelled()` inside your `AsyncTask`. Here, you can clean-up, dismiss the `ProgressBar`, show an error message etc. `onCancelled()` will be called after `cancel()', `onPostExecute()` will not be called.

Comment: In your loop or background procedure you need to check for AsyncTak.isCancelled(). In this way you can stop and exit the background operation as soon as you call cancel on the AsyncTask. Calling cancel doesn't actually stop the AsyncTask!

Comment: @type-a1pha Hi Could you explain this more or point me to an example pls?

Comment: Check here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html the code snippet in the introduction.

Comment: I've just been looking at that myself. I don't see how i can have a loop in my doInBackground method. I'm not download and publishing progress anything. How can i check in a loop the value of isCancelled in my situation. I'm not sure how that example applies

Comment: Yeah, sorry. Why can't you call dismiss from your caller (e.g. main thread) as soon as it knows that the dialog needs to be closed? Regarding stopping the AsyncTask, you can't! An AsyncTask is an utility abstraction of what actually is a ThreadPoolExecutor, so there is no public method to just kill the thread. Cancel is your best shot, but if the long-running operation is outside of your control then you have to wait for it to finish. I also want you to notice that the use of ProgressDialog is deprecated by the Android UI guidelines: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

Comment: @type-a1pha: I'm not seeing that ProgressDialog is deprecated.